# C# binding JSon list of different object types to their models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

I'm trying to send a JSon back to the controller with an attribute that is a list of a generic class. Inside that list, there will be instances of different specialized classes. Like the following:

```
class Coluna 
{ (...) }

class ColunaInformacao : Coluna 
{ (...) }

class ColunaResposta : Coluna
{ (...) }
```

and the list attribute itself:

```
class Apuracao 
{
  public List<Coluna> Colunas { get; set; }
}
```

When on the view, I'm succesfully creating a JSon with an `Apuracao` instance and it's list attribute (`Colunas`) in which I have instances of `ColunaInformacao` and `ColunaResposta` types.

Problem is: When the controller binds the JSon to my model, it's creating all items on the list attribute as of the type `Coluna`, and discarding the extra data from the specific classes (`ColunaInformacao` and `ColunaResposta`).

Any way to accomplish the correct type on the binding?

EDIT:
Just to clarify a bit more:
I'm sending data from the view to the controller.
The JSON is perfectly formed.
The controller receives it and binds it without any problems.

My question rely on the fact that JavaScript classes are loosely typed, so, there isn't a "class type" on it (except by the generic [object]). When binding a string version of a JavaScript class (JSon) how would the defaultBinder know which specialized class it has to use on my C# model.

Comment: how are you doing your json serialization?

Comment: "by hand"... That is: I'm buiding up an object (with all correct attributes names) and after that, calling JSON.stringify on it. And the controller is getting all right, just not the instances types...

Comment: So binding wrong going from the controller to view? or vice versa from the view to the controller?  If your using JSON.Stringify i get the impression your on your view (view.cshtml).  If your own your controller have you tried netwonsoft.json.convert?  when i use that on controllers it works fine getting all the properties from classes that implement interfaces and also inherit base classes

Comment: @ChampChris, the binding itself is working. The problem is more subtle, though. The `Colunas` attribute is a list of `Coluna`, and that's what the defaultBinder is instanciating (`Coluna`s instances). But problem is that i'm filling that list with specialized classes (classes that inherit from `Coluna`) and since JavaScript classes are loozely typed, the binder is not getting this...

Comment: Is it possible to have classes strongly typed and created in c# and created to JSON strings server side and passed to the view?  It sounds like you creating the objects client side in the view.

Comment: @ChampChris no, unfortunately it is not possible (it's the key functionality to let the user create such instances in the View itself). But, for a test measure, I will follow your suggestion and create such list in server side, render it on the view and send it back to the controller just to se if it can recognize the specialized classes instances (my guess is: no, it can't). The problem lies on the JavaScript technology itself - a JavaScript object does not have a "class", so, for the binding process it relies on the model specification (which, in this case presents a `List<Coluna>`)

Comment: @ChampChris, my research so far indicated me 2 diferent possible paths: #1 to create a model that separates the `Coluna` specialized types (like `List<ColunaInformacao> ColunasInformacoes` and `List<ColunaResposta> ColunasRespostas`) and use it to send the instances separated by types (which is not so good, because the real implementation have lots of specializations and not only 2);

Comment: #2 is to implement a custom Binder which is capable of differentiating each specialized class and instantiating the proper type (something vaguely like this: [link](http://ivonna.biz/blog/2012/2/2/custom-aspnet-model-binders-series,-part-3-subclassing-your-models.aspx)

Comment: yeah the only other thing i can think of would be to try to have specialization created with no base class, but like u said with a lot of specializations that could be a nightmare to manage.

Comment: Just looked at the link, looks like it is for strongly type models.  I would interested to know if it works.